# Meteor.call don't work inside sweetalert confirmation box

Tags: meteor, sweetalert

I've got an event to delete intern messages in my app : a button in front, with a click event who call a method. Everything works fine.

But before the call of the method, I'd like a confirm box "Are you sure you want to delete this message ?"

With the standard confirm js function, works fine. But the standard js confirmbox... No styling allowed.

So my idea was to use sweetalert : everything go well, the berts notifications as well, but no message is deleted..

Below my event, confirm box version & sweetalert version, and the method.

Thanks!

**confirm box version**

```
Template.Users.events({
    'click .toggle-admin': function() {
        Meteor.call('toggleAdmin', this._id);
    },
    'click button.delete-message':function() {
        if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            Meteor.call('deleteMessage', this._id, function(error) {
                if(error) {
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: error.reason,
                        type: 'danger'
                    });
                } else {
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Message deleted.',
                        type: 'success'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**sweetalert version**

```
Template.Users.events({
    'click .toggle-admin': function() {
        Meteor.call('toggleAdmin', this._id);
    },
    'click button.delete-message':function() {
        swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text: "You will not be able to recover this message!",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
          confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
        }).then(function (){
            Meteor.call('deleteMessage', this._id, function(error) {
                if(error) {
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: error.reason,
                        type: 'danger'
                    });
                } else {
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Message deleted.',
                        type: 'success'
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    }
});
```

**method**

```
Meteor.methods({
    insertMessage: function(message) {
        ContactMessages.insert(message);
    },
    deleteMessage: function(messageId) {
        ContactMessages.remove({_id: messageId});
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess `this` is not what you are expecting it to be inside the callback.

Comment: @MasterAM Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native `window.confirm()` is synchronous, and blocks the JS thread of execution. This means that once the user responds to the prompt, a value is returned by it and execution continues from that point. That is the reason you can use `this._id` successfully.

With an asynchronous API such as [swal2](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/)'s, which uses promises, you pass a function to handle it once it is resolved or rejected (what you pass to `then`). In those callbacks, `this` no longer points to the original object, so you need to preserve access to it (or to other required data) by using a closure or by lexically binding it with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Using a closure:

```js
Template.Users.events({
  'click button.delete-message'() {
    const id = this._id;
    swal({
        // ...
    }).then(function (){ // `id` is available from external function
      Meteor.call('deleteMessage', id, function(error) {
        // ...
      });
    })
  }
});
```

lexical scope binding using an arrow function:

```js
Template.Users.events({
  'click button.delete-message'() {
    swal({
        // ...
    }).then(() => { //bound to the current `this`
      Meteor.call('deleteMessage', this._id, function(error) {
        // ...
      });
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Works very fine. Thank you!