# Why is `this` undefined in a Blaze event handler?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm stuck in a reply function to intern messages: the `email reply-sending` function works fine (if I choose manually in the code the `to` field), but I'm failing, when I choose the message to reply, to select automatically the email in the `contact-messages` collection (field `email`) with my `Meteor.methods`.

In few words :

- `var to = "bob@bob.com"` => ok
- `var to = this.email` => no value catched

Here below my event on the reply form submit and the method

**Event (can't catch `var to = this.email`)**

```
Template.ContactReplyModal.events({
    'click .send-message':function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Meteor.call('replyMessage', this._id, function(error) {
            if(error) {
                Bert.alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: error.reason,
                    type: 'danger'
                });
            } else {
                var to = this.email;
                var from = "my@mail.com";
                var subject = $('#reply-subject').val();
                var message = $('#reply-message').val();

                if(message != '' && subject != '') {
                    Meteor.call('sendEmailContact', to, from, subject, message, function (error) {
                        if(error) {
                            Bert.alert({
                                title: 'Error',
                                message: error.reason,
                                type: 'danger'
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('#reply-message').val('');
                            $('#reply-subject').val('');
                            Bert.alert({
                                title: 'Success',
                                message: 'Message sended.',
                                type: 'success'
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: 'Message error.',
                        type: 'danger'
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    },
    //Close events for ContactReplyModal
    'click .close-login': ()=> {
        Session.set('nav-toggle-contactreply', '');
    },
    'click .modal-overlay-contactreply': ()=> {
        Session.set('nav-toggle-contactreply', '');
    }
});
```

**Method (using here the `replyMessage` function)**

```
//Contact Method
Meteor.methods({
    insertMessage: function(message) {
        ContactMessages.insert(message);
    },
    openMessage: function(messageId) {
        ContactMessages.update({_id: messageId}, {$set: {new: false}});
    },
    replyMessage: function(messageId) {
        ContactMessages.findOne({_id: messageId});
    },
    deleteMessage: function(messageId) {
        ContactMessages.remove({_id: messageId});
    }
});
```

---

#### EDIT

The bind of the variable `email` with an arrow function doesn't work.

So maybe it is an issue of capturing the variable?

I cant' read `console.log (this);` and `console.log (this.email);` says `undefined`.

Here below is my message collection.

```
"_id": "6c3478WugEajr6zaw",
  "name": "bob",
  "email": "bob@bob.com",
  "message": "This is a try.",
  "submitted": "2017-01-05T15:19:04.642Z",
  "new": true
```

I really don't understand, cause this below event works on the `openMessage` method (so the right message is correctly identified from the others)

```
//CLIENTSIDE  
  'click .open-message':function() {
            Meteor.call('openMessage', this._id, function(error) {
                if(error) {
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: error.reason,
                        type: 'danger'
                    });
                }
            });
        }

//SERVERSIDE

    Meteor.methods({
        insertMessage: function(message) {
            ContactMessages.insert(message);
        },
        openMessage: function(messageId) {
            ContactMessages.update({_id: messageId}, {$set: {new: false}});
        },
        replyMessage: function(message) {
            ContactMessages.findOne({_id: message});
        },
        deleteMessage: function(messageId) {
            ContactMessages.remove({_id: messageId});
        }
    });
```

---

#### EDIT 2

As asked, below the template & the js linked to. The method is already showed and an example of the data in collection too.

**template (`contact-reply.html`)**

```
<template name="ContactReply">
    <h3>Reply</h3>
    <h3>To: {{email}}</h3>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="reply-subject" id="reply-subject" placeholder="Subject"/>
    <br>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="reply-message" id="reply-message" rows="6"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success send-message">Send</button>

</template>


<template name="ContactReplyModal">
    <div class="contactreply-modal {{$.Session.get 'nav-toggle-contactreply'}}">
        <i class="fa fa-close close-login"></i>
        <h3>Send a reply</h3>
        {{> ContactReply}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-overlay-contactreply"></div>
</template>
```

**js of the template (`contact-reply.js`)**

```
import './contact-reply.html';




Template.ContactReplyModal.events({
    'click .send-message':function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this);
        Meteor.call('replyMessage', this._id, (error) => {
            if(error) {
                Bert.alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: error.reason,
                    type: 'danger'
                });
            } else {
                console.log (this.email);
                const to = this.email;
                var from = "my@mail.com";
                var subject = $('#reply-subject').val();
                var message = $('#reply-message').val();

                if(message != '' && subject != '') {
                    Meteor.call('sendEmailContact', to, from, subject, message, (error) => {
                        if(error) {
                            Bert.alert({
                                title: 'Error',
                                message: error.reason,
                                type: 'danger'
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('#reply-message').val('');
                            $('#reply-subject').val('');
                            Bert.alert({
                                title: 'Success',
                                message: 'Message sended.',
                                type: 'success'
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: 'Message error.',
                        type: 'danger'
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    },
    //Close events for ContactReplyModal
    'click .close-login': ()=> {
        Session.set('nav-toggle-contactreply', '');
    },
    'click .modal-overlay-contactreply': ()=> {
        Session.set('nav-toggle-contactreply', '');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is *very* similar to [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41463899/268093) from the other day. See if you can make use of it. If not, I will write a short answer for this one as well.

Comment: @MasterAM I was thinking your help was on an asynchronous/synchronous issue. Is it the case also here? Anyway, I tried to export your past answer to this case, and failed... Sorry for being such a newbie, but a short answer will be _so much_ appreciated!

Comment: @MasterAM Can't make it works : so I edited my question with some thoughts...

Comment: Show your template's code and whatever data you have supplied to it.

Comment: @MasterAM As asked, all in my edited question. Thanks.

Comment: The `.open-message` button is in the `ContactReply` template, while the handler is bound to the `ContactReplyModal` template. I guess that may be why it does not have a data context.

Comment: You're so right! My mistake - a mix in templates, sub-templates, etc.. Sorry and thank you for your time.

Comment: I added the relevant details to the answer. Please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is important to be sure that the [**data context**](http://blazejs.org/guide/understanding-blaze.html#Re-rendering) is correct. 
Each element within the template is rendered with a certain data context. If you target them in a template event handler, the data context will be available to the handler via `this`.

If you target an element that is **not rendered by the current template** (e.g, rendered by a third-party library or belongs to a sub-template), it will not have a data contest, which is what causes your data context to be `undefined`).

Having that fixed, assuming the data context (the external function's `this`) is indeed what you expect in the event handler (i.e, has an `email` field), you need to make it available to the **callback**. You can capture it in a local variable and make it available in a **closure** or lexically bind it with an **arrow function**:

```js
Template.ContactReplyModal.events({
    'click .send-message':function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this); // to make sure that it is what you are expecting.
        Meteor.call('replyMessage', this._id, (e) => { // note the arrow function
            if(e) {
                // ...
            } else {
                const to = this.email;
                // ...
                if(message != '' && subject != '') {
                    Meteor.call('sendEmailContact', to, from, subject, message, (e) => {
                        if(e) {
                            // ...
                        } else {
                            // ...
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
    },
    // ...
});
```

However, it does not seem like a good idea to use multiple nested method calls. It would probably be better to do it all in a single method call.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the template variable in template events using this, you can access them by the 2nd parameter in your events, here is your code, hope it will work

```
Template.ContactReplyModal.events({
'click .send-message'(e, instance) {
e.preventDefault();
Meteor.call('replyMessage', this._id, function(error) {
    if(error) {
        Bert.alert({
            title: 'Error',
            message: error.reason,
            type: 'danger'
        });
    } else {
        var to = instance.email;
        var from = "my@mail.com";
        var subject = $('#reply-subject').val();
        var message = $('#reply-message').val();

        if(message != '' && subject != '') {
            Meteor.call('sendEmailContact', to, from, subject, message, function (error) {
                if(error) {
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: error.reason,
                        type: 'danger'
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#reply-message').val('');
                    $('#reply-subject').val('');
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Message sended.',
                        type: 'success'
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            Bert.alert({
                title: 'Error',
                message: 'Message error.',
                type: 'danger'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

},
});

Comment: Doesn't work... There is two lines changed from my code right ? `'click .send-message'(e, instance) {` & `var to = instance.email;`

Comment: Yeah u r right. Have you initialized `this.email` in template onRendered or OnCreated function?

Comment: I don't. Any example?

Comment: `Template.ContactReplyModal.onRendered(function(){
   this.email = Session.get("email);
});`

Comment: change `Meteor.call('replyMessage', this._id, function(error){` to `Meteor.call('replyMessage', this._id, (error) => {`